# Finding op code / bytes in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

For these lines of code, I need to find the Op code, number of bytes of object code, and the number of clock cycles required for execution. Assume the value references a word in memory and that Double references a doubleword.

```
sub wordOp, ax
sub eax,10
add dblOp, 10
add eax,[ebx]
```

Could anyone explain to me how I would get these values for the lines of code?

Comment: Assembly language (and opcodes in general) depends on the underlying platform (compiler, CPU, etc). What platform are you using?

Comment: intel 80X86. Or do I need be more more specific than that?

Comment: Compiler (or at least, what IDE are you using, is it Visual Studio)?

Comment: Yes, visual studio to compile it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but it seems that all you need to do is to put this code in an `__asm` clause:

```
void main()
{
    short a;
    long  b;
    __asm
    {
        sub a,ax
        sub eax,10
        add b,10
        add eax,[ebx]
    }
}
```

Then, place a breakpoint on the first line in the `__asm` clause, and run the program in Debug mode. Then, right-click the text, and choose `Go To Disassembly`, which will show you this:

```
          sub a,ax
0030139E  sub word ptr [a],ax
          sub eax,10
003013A2  sub eax,0Ah
          add b,10
003013A5  add dword ptr [b],0Ah
          add eax,[ebx]
003013A9  add eax,dword ptr [ebx]
...
003013AB
```

The addresses above are in my local program of course, but the size of the code can be easily calculated as 0x003013AB - 0030139E = D, i.e., 13 bytes.

BTW, I'm not sure about the `short a` and `long b` (it could just as well be `int a` and `double b`), so you'll need to ask whoever gave you this task about the exact meaning of `wordOp` and `dblOp`...

Comment: @dwelch: by saving the file as `.s` and compiling it?

Answer (score 0):

I like this online assembler:
https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly

But the number of clock cycles depends of the cpu architectur.

Dirk